# go: calling methods on interface creates new copy as part of type assertion, need to assert type of pointer to call methods from pointer

Tags: go, pointers, methods, interface

So i have this structure i have implemented for a kanban here's a bit of it that's relevant for the question:

```golang
type Menu struct {
    Projects dll.DLL
}

type Project struct {
    Title  string
    Lists  dll.DLL
    Labels dll.DLL
}

type List struct {
    Title string
    Cards dll.DLL
}

func StartMenu() *Menu {
    return &Menu{
        Projects: dll.New(),
    }
}

func (m *Menu) AddProject(title string) {
    project := Project{
        Title: title,
        Lists: dll.New(),
    }
    m.Projects.Append(project)
}

func (p *Project) AddList(title string) {
    list := List{
        Title: title,
        Cards: dll.New(),
    }
    p.Lists.Append(list)
}
```

Now dll.DLL is a helper package i created to abstract usage of data structures, in this case a doubly linked list: [implementation here](https://github.com/Anacardo89/ds/blob/master/lists/dll/dll.go)
Since i wanted to abstract it, the values in the nodes are all interfaces, seems the best approach for it.

So create some mock data to check it's working and surprise, it's not

```golang
menu := kanban.StartMenu()
menu.AddProject("project1")
project1, err := menu.Projects.WalkTo(0)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
project1Val := project1.GetVal().(kanban.Project)
project1Val.AddList("List 1")
```

that's because `project1.GetVal().(kanban.Project)` gives me a copy of the project, so when `project1Val.AddList("List 1")` is called, it's affecting the copy and not the original, nothing new for this side, normal behaviour.

So i added a new method for `dll.Node` `GetValPtr()` which returns a pointer to the value of the node, since `Node.Val` is an interface, it returns `*interface{}`, and here's the tricky part:
I can't assert the type of `*interface{}` because it's not `interface{}`, makes sense, a pointer is not the thing, however i should be able to assert the underlying type for that pointer, and use it after it's been asserted to be said type, but the only way i figured to do it is to dereference the pointer and then assert the type, which will give me the same as in the above code, just with extra steps. So again, a copy of the value.

```golang
project1Val := project1.GetValPtr()
proj1 := (*project1Val).(kanban.Project)
proj1.AddList("List 1")
```

Is there a way to assert the underlying type of a pointer in order to use the method on my original object instead of the copy?

Comment: You don't need `GetValPtr`. Simply put pointers into the list, not values.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I'm sorry mr gold badge, your comment gets me no closer to the solution, yes, i am aware that if i modify GetVal to return a pointer i don't need GetValPtr, i'm also aware that if i define node.Val as a pointer i also don't need GetValPtr.
Now for the question, mr Wrote-the-book-on-Go, can i assert the underlying type of a pointer to interface in order to get a pointer to kanban.Project and use a method from it? Or do i have to go about it some other way?
If you have time to leave an irrelevant comment, why don't you take the time to provide a relevant answer?

Comment: If you store a `kanban.Project` in the list, you cannot get a useful pointer, you can only get a pointer to a copy of it. What I suggested was store a `*kanban.Project` in your list.

Comment: @BurakSerdar let me see if i get it right, you're saying to store `*kanban.Project` as a field in `kanban.List`? Referencing the parent in the child? That makes sense on a first approach, but to solve my problem i would have to rework the whole functionality of it (and the levels below that are also affected), since i create the DLL on `m.AddProject()`, when i add a list i call the parent and append to the DLL created on the parent, if i slap a pointer to the parent then i have to create another list to the parent but the list i created that points to the parent is not in the parent DLL

Comment: What I am saying is, instead of `m.Projects.Append(project)`, use `m.Projects.Append(&project)`. Then, you will get a `*Project` from the list, not a `Project`

Comment: @BurakSerdar I saw this only now, you were right, and i was grosly misunderstanding, you can see the changes i made in the answer below, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So i solved it, and i think it's in part what @BurakSerdar was trying to tell me in comments, but i was understanding it differently. Thank you, in your eyes it was simple, and now it's simple for me as well, even if i had to go the long way around to get there.

basically i started appending pointers instead of values when creating the objects:

```golang
func (m *Menu) AddProject(title string) {
    project := &Project{
        Title: title,
        Lists: dll.New(),
    }
    m.Projects.Append(project)
}

func (p *Project) AddList(title string) {
    list := &List{
        Title: title,
        Cards: dll.New(),
    }
    p.Lists.Append(list)
}
```

and retrieving a pointer into the value which gives me exactly what i want

```golang
project1Val := project1.GetVal().(*kanban.Project)
```

it works, no errors, here's the output:

```bash
projects:
- title: project1
  lists:
  - title: List 1
    cards:
    - title: Card 1
      description: ""
      checklist: []
      card_labels: []
    - title: Card 2
      description: ""
      checklist: []
      card_labels: []
  - title: List 2
    cards:
    - title: Card 1
      description: ""
      checklist: []
      card_labels: []
    - title: Card 2
      description: ""
      checklist: []
      card_labels: []
  labels:
  - title: Label 1
    color: "30"
  - title: Label 2
    color: "50"
- title: project2
  lists:
  - title: List 1
    cards:
    - title: Card 1
      description: ""
      checklist: []
      card_labels: []
    - title: Card 2
      description: ""
      checklist: []
      card_labels: []
  - title: List 2
    cards:
    - title: Card 1
      description: ""
      checklist: []
      card_labels: []
    - title: Card 2
      description: ""
      checklist: []
      card_labels: []
  labels:
  - title: Label 1
    color: "30"
  - title: Label 2
    color: "50"
```